# How to concat buffers with delimiter in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I'm trying to concat two buffers with a space in between them in Node.js.

Here is my code.

```
var buff1 = new Buffer("Jumping");
var buff2 = new Buffer("Japang");
var buffSpace = new Buffer(1);
buffSpace[0] = "32";
var newBuff = Buffer.concat([buff1, buffSpace, buff2], (buff1.length + buff2.length + buffSpace.length));
console.log(newBuff.toString());
```

As per official doc, the first argument will be the Array list of Buffer objects. Hence I've created **buffSpace** for space.

> **Class Method**: Buffer.concat(list[, totalLength]) 
>   **list** : Array List of Buffer objects to concat  
>   **totalLength**: Number Total length of the buffers when concatenated

I'm getting the result as expected but not sure whether it is right way to do so. Please suggest if any better solution to achieve the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three changes I would suggest.

First, if you are using Node v6, use `Buffer.from()` instead of `new Buffer()`, as [the latter is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_array).

Second, you don't need to pass an argument for `totalLength` to `Buffer.concat()`, since [it will be calculated automatically](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) from the length of all of the buffers passed. While the docs note it will be faster to pass a total length, this will really only be true if you pass a constant value. What you are doing above is computing the length and then passing that, which is what the `concat()` function will do internally anyway.

Finally, I would recommend putting this in a function that works like [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), but for buffers.

```
function joinBuffers(buffers, delimiter = ' ') {
  let d = Buffer.from(delimiter);

  return buffers.reduce((prev, b) => Buffer.concat([prev, d, b]));
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
let buf1 = Buffer.from('Foo');
let buf2 = Buffer.from('Bar');
let buf3 = Buffer.from('Baz');

let joined = joinBuffers([buf1, buf2, buf3]);

console.log(joined.toString()); // Foo Bar Baz
```

Or set a custom delimiter like this:

```
let joined2 = joinBuffers([buf1, buf2, buf3], ' and ');

console.log(joined2.toString()); // Foo and Bar and Baz
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Since I'm still using v0.12.x and moving to v4.x, I've to stay on `new Buffer()` till I move to v6.x. By the way great suggestion. Thanks Again :)

Comment: @Kikit Thanks for pointing out that `Buffer.from()` isn't even available in Node <= 4. That was an oversight on my part, and I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also the arrow function and Default Parameter value is a part of ES6 which is available in node from v4. Some features of Arrow function supported in v0.12.x by using `--harmony` flag. [Check Here](http://node.green/)

Comment: @Kikit Well I knew that at least, but ES2015 is so much more beautiful that I always use it in my examples. I think people can translate to the backward and primitive ES5 syntax if they have to.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Buffer stream and save it to file as:

```
   const data = [];
    req.on('data', stream => {
        data.push(stream);
    });

    req.on('close', () => {
        const parsedData = Buffer.concat(data).toString('utf8');
        fs.writeFileSync('./test.text', parsedData);
    });
```